# Delphi Bluetooth LE heart rate profile access

Tags: delphi, bluetooth-lowenergy

Im following the Delphi test project to read data from a Bluetooth device that implements
the Heart Rate Service. so... A perfect fit one would think for the test project.

Unfortunately when it comes to discovering the services per
Bluetooth1.DiscoverServices(adev)
an exception is thrown that the device needs to be paired.
In addition if I do not issue the command the services array of the Bluetooth LE device is empty
(only the advertised list is filled).

So... I cannot pair this device and also for my understanding I don't need to do that in BT LE -
so why is that exception there and how can I get the services otherwise?

In addition the OnEndDiscoverDevices is never called - only if I cancel the Discovery process the event gets called

here is the complete code:

```
unit ufrmBTLETest;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, System.Bluetooth, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  System.Bluetooth.Components, Vcl.ComCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    BTLE: TBluetoothLE;
    memLog: TMemo;
    tvDevices: TTreeView;
    timCancel: TTimer;
    Button2: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BTLEDiscoverLEDevice(const Sender: TObject;
      const ADevice: TBluetoothLEDevice; Rssi: Integer;
      const ScanResponse: TScanResponse);
    procedure BTLEServicesDiscovered(const Sender: TObject;
      const AServiceList: TBluetoothGattServiceList);
    procedure BTLEServiceAdded(const Sender: TObject;
      const AService: TBluetoothGattService;
      const AGattStatus: TBluetoothGattStatus);
    procedure BTLEEndDiscoverDevices(const Sender: TObject;
      const ADeviceList: TBluetoothLEDeviceList);
    procedure BTLEEndDiscoverServices(const Sender: TObject;
      const AServiceList: TBluetoothGattServiceList);
    procedure timCancelTimer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure tvDevicesClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  System.StrUtils, System.Generics.Collections;

{$R *.dfm}

const HRSERVICE: TBluetoothUUID = '{0000180D-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}';
      HRMEASUREMENT_CHARACTERISTIC: TBluetoothUUID  = '{00002A37-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}';


function bytesToStr( aval : TBytes ) : string;
var i : integer;
begin
     for i := 0 to Length(aval) do
         Result := Result + IntToHex(aval[i], 2);
end;

procedure TForm1.BTLEDiscoverLEDevice(const Sender: TObject;
  const ADevice: TBluetoothLEDevice; Rssi: Integer;
  const ScanResponse: TScanResponse);
var
  i: Integer;
  arr : TArray<TPair<TScanResponseKey, TBytes>>;

begin
     memLog.Lines.Add('Discovered: ' + ADevice.Identifier);
     memLog.Lines.Add('Name: ' + ADevice.DeviceName);

     arr := scanResponse.ToArray;
     for i := 0 to Length(arr) - 1 do
     begin
          memLog.Lines.Add(Format('Resp %d, %d, %s',[i, Integer(arr[i].Key), BytesToSTr( arr[i].Value )]));
     end;
end;

procedure TForm1.BTLEEndDiscoverDevices(const Sender: TObject;
  const ADeviceList: TBluetoothLEDeviceList);
var i, j: Integer;
    ti : TTreeNode;
    aDev : TBluetoothLEDevice;
    ser : TBluetoothGattService;
begin
     for i := 0 to ADeviceList.Count - 1 do
     begin
          aDev := ADeviceList[i];
          if true then //aDev.DeviceName = 'medilogHR' then
          begin
               ti := tvDevices.Items.AddChild(nil, ifthen( aDev.DeviceName = '', aDev.Identifier, aDev.DeviceName));
          end;
     end;
end;

procedure TForm1.BTLEEndDiscoverServices(const Sender: TObject;
  const AServiceList: TBluetoothGattServiceList);
begin
     memLog.Lines.Add('Services ended:' + AServiceList.Count.ToString);
end;

procedure TForm1.BTLEServiceAdded(const Sender: TObject;
  const AService: TBluetoothGattService;
  const AGattStatus: TBluetoothGattStatus);
begin
     memlog.Lines.Add('Service added: ' + AService.UUIDName);
     memLog.Lines.Add('Gatt: ' + IntToStr(Integer(agattStatus)));
end;

procedure TForm1.BTLEServicesDiscovered(const Sender: TObject;
  const AServiceList: TBluetoothGattServiceList);
begin
     memLog.Lines.Add('Service Discovered');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
     tvDevices.Items.Clear;
     timCancel.Interval := 18000;
     if BTLE.DiscoverDevices(timCancel.Interval, [HRSERVICE]) then 
        timCancel.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  HeartRateService: TGUID = '{0000180D-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}';
var
  ABLEAdvertisedDataFilter: TBluetoothLEScanFilter;
  ABLEAdvertisedDataFilterList: TBluetoothLEScanFilterList;
begin
  ABLEAdvertisedDataFilter:= TBluetoothLEScanFilter.Create;
  ABLEAdvertisedDataFilterList:= TBluetoothLEScanFilterList.Create;
  ABLEAdvertisedDataFilter.ServiceUUID:= HeartRateService; 
  ABLEAdvertisedDataFilterList.Add(ABLEAdvertisedDataFilter);

  timCancel.Interval := 18000;
  btle.CurrentManager.StartDiscovery(18000,ABLEAdvertisedDataFilterList);
  timCancel.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.timCancelTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
     timCancel.Enabled := False;
     btle.CancelDiscovery;

end;

procedure TForm1.tvDevicesClick(Sender: TObject);
var aDev : TBluetoothLEDevice;
    j : integer;
    scanResp : TScanResponse;
    arr : TArray<TPair<TScanResponseKey, TBytes>>;
begin
     if tvDevices.Items.Count > 0 then
     begin
          for aDev in btle.CurrentManager.AllDiscoveredDevices do
          begin
               if aDev.Paired then
               begin
                    timcancel.enabled := True;
                    aDev.DiscoverServices;
               end
               else
               begin
                    arr := aDev.AdvertisedData.ToArray;
                    for j := 0 to Length(arr) - 1 do
                    begin
                          memlog.Lines.Add(IntToStr( integer(arr[j].Key) )+ ': ' + bytesToStr(arr[j].Value));
                    end;                                                   
               end;
          end;
     end;
end;

end.
```

Form data:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 415
  ClientWidth = 514
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 8
    Top = 8
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Scan'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object memLog: TMemo
    Left = 16
    Top = 272
    Width = 490
    Height = 135
    Lines.Strings = (
      'memLog')
    TabOrder = 1
  end
  object tvDevices: TTreeView
    Left = 16
    Top = 39
    Width = 490
    Height = 227
    Indent = 19
    TabOrder = 2
    OnClick = tvDevicesClick
  end
  object Button2: TButton
    Left = 112
    Top = 8
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button2'
    TabOrder = 3
    OnClick = Button2Click
  end
  object BTLE: TBluetoothLE
    Enabled = True
    OnDiscoverLEDevice = BTLEDiscoverLEDevice
    OnServicesDiscovered = BTLEServicesDiscovered
    OnEndDiscoverDevices = BTLEEndDiscoverDevices
    OnEndDiscoverServices = BTLEEndDiscoverServices
    OnServiceAdded = BTLEServiceAdded
    Left = 440
    Top = 40
  end
  object timCancel: TTimer
    Enabled = False
    OnTimer = timCancelTimer
    Left = 384
    Top = 40
  end
end
```

I'm using Delphi 10.3 update 3
What is my basic misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching the German Delphi sites I discovered quite a few similar problems. In a nutshell Delphi 10.3 does not support that properly (pairing is not required any more) and a QC is already filed. Hope that changes in 10.4.

Update:
I edited System.Win.BluetoothWinRT such that the "pairingless" state can also query the services by following the c# implementation of the microsoft bluetooth le examples.

1) Change TWinRTBluetoothLEDevice.CheckInitialized to

```
  // the exception was the old code...
  if FId = 0 then
    begin
      //raise EBluetoothDeviceException.Create(SBluetoothLEDeviceNotPaired);

      if TAsyncOperation<IAsyncOperation_1__IBluetoothLEDevice>.Wait(
        TBluetoothLEDevice.Statics.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(FAddress), LBLEDeviceAsyncOp) = AsyncStatus.Completed then
      begin
        FBluetoothLEDevice := LBLEDeviceAsyncOp.GetResults;
        FClosed := False;
        if DeviceName = '' then
          FDeviceName := FBluetoothLEDevice.Name.ToString;
        FConnectionStatusChangeDelegate := TConnectionStatusChangeEventHandler.Create(Self);
        FBluetoothLEDevice.add_ConnectionStatusChanged(FConnectionStatusChangeDelegate);
exit;
      end;
```

and parts of DoDiscoverService to

```
var
  I: Integer;
  LGattService: GenericAttributeProfile_IGattDeviceService;
  dev3 : IBluetoothLEDevice3;
  res3 : IAsyncOperation_1__GenericAttributeProfile_IGattDeviceServicesResult;
  serviceRes : GenericAttributeProfile_IGattDeviceServicesResult;
  LGattServices: IVectorView_1__GenericAttributeProfile_IGattDeviceService;
begin
  Result := True;
  FServices.Clear;
  CheckInitialized;
  if FID = 0 then
  begin
      dev3 := fBluetoothLEDevice as IBluetoothLEDevice3;

      if dev3 = nil then
         raise EBluetoothDeviceException.Create(SBluetoothLEDeviceNotPaired);

      if TAsyncOperation<IAsyncOperation_1__GenericAttributeProfile_IGattDeviceServicesResult>.Wait(

         dev3.GetGattServicesAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached), res3 ) = AsyncStatus.Completed then 
      begin
           serviceRes := res3.GetResults;

           LGattServices := serviceRes.Services;

           for I := 0 to LGattServices.Size - 1 do
           begin
                LGattService := LGattServices.GetAt(I);
                FServices.Add(TWinRTBluetoothGattService.Create(Self, LGattService, TBluetoothServiceType.Primary));
           end;
      end; 
  end
```

This pattern has to be followed in the TWinRTBluetoothGattService.DoGetCharacteristics and the
TWinRTBluetoothGattCharacteristic.DoGetDescriptors functions.

Extension to the DoGetCharacteristics Function:

```
var
  I: Integer;
  LGattCharacteristics: IVectorView_1__GenericAttributeProfile_IGattCharacteristic;
  charactRes : GenericAttributeProfile_IGattCharacteristicsResult;
  service3 : GenericAttributeProfile_IGattDeviceService3;
  characteristics3 : IAsyncOperation_1__GenericAttributeProfile_IGattCharacteristicsResult;
begin
  CheckNotClosed;
  FCharacteristics.Clear;

  if FDevice.FId = 0 then
  begin
       service3 := FGattService as GenericAttributeProfile_IGattDeviceService3;

       if TAsyncOperation<IAsyncOperation_1__GenericAttributeProfile_IGattCharacteristicsResult>.Wait(
                        service3.GetCharacteristicsAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached), characteristics3 ) = AsyncStatus.Completed then 
       begin
            charactRes := characteristics3.GetResults;    
            LGattCharacteristics := charactRes.Characteristics;
            if LGattCharacteristics.Size > 0 then
               for I := 0 to LGattCharacteristics.Size - 1 do
                   FCharacteristics.Add(TWinRTBluetoothGattCharacteristic.Create(Self, LGattCharacteristics.GetAt(I)));
       end;
  end

//old code
```

Extension to the dogetdescriptors function (note this function does not perfectly performs the necessary checks...)

```
var
  LGattDescriptors: IVectorView_1__GenericAttributeProfile_IGattDescriptor;
  I: Integer;
  characteristic3 : GenericAttributeProfile_IGattCharacteristic3;
  descriptorRes3 : IAsyncOperation_1__GenericAttributeProfile_IGattDescriptorsResult;
  descrRes : GenericAttributeProfile_IGattDescriptorsResult;
begin
  FDescriptors.Clear;
  LGattDescriptors := (FGattCharacteristic as GenericAttributeProfile_IGattCharacteristic2).GetAllDescriptors;
  if LGattDescriptors.Size > 0 then
  begin
       for I := 0 to LGattDescriptors.Size - 1 do
           FDescriptors.Add(TWinRTBluetoothGattDescriptor.Create(Self, LGattDescriptors.GetAt(I)));
  end
  else
  begin
       characteristic3 := FGattCharacteristic as GenericAttributeProfile_IGattCharacteristic3;

       if TAsyncOperation<IAsyncOperation_1__GenericAttributeProfile_IGattDescriptorsResult>.Wait(
                        characteristic3.GetDescriptorsAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached), descriptorRes3 ) = AsyncStatus.Completed then 
       begin
            descrRes := descriptorRes3.GetResults;    
            LGattDescriptors := descrRes.Descriptors;
            for I := 0 to LGattDescriptors.Size - 1 do
                FDescriptors.Add(TWinRTBluetoothGattDescriptor.Create(Self, LGattDescriptors.GetAt(I)));
       end;

  end;
  Result := FDescriptors;
end;
```